# VS code do not recognise relative path as filename

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have the following folder structure

```
---data/
    |-----test.csv
---pythonscript/
    |-----myscript.ipynb
    |-----myscript.py
```

The following codes work just fine in `myscript.ipynb`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('../data/test.csv')
```

However, when I moved the same codes to `myscript.py` and run it using VS code, it shows me the `FileNotFoundError` that `'../data/test.csv'` does not exist.
I checked:

- both jupyter notebook and VScode are using Python 3.8.3 64-bit ('base':conda) interpreter
- They have the same cwd as `pythonscript/`
- When I use absolute path of `test.csv` on VScode instead, it works also fine.

Because I are sharing the codes with a peer, I want to avoid typing absolute path as possible.

The temporary solution I came up with, is to have additionally:

```
import os
os.chdir("..")
f1=os.getcwd()+'/data/'
df1=pd.read_csv(f1+'test.csv')
```

But it is not really succinct. I wonder if there is a standard solution for this kind of annoyance in VS code? I am very new to VS code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the information you described, I created the relevant files, and the following are the results of my testing in different folder structures:

[image]

[image]